# How to fine tune a pretrain Alexnet in Caffe with images having a gray channel?

Tags: caffe

When I fine tune the AlexNet with my data having one channel gray images. But caffe-AlexNet is three channel input, I fine tune the conv1 layer and fc8 layer. I got the 90% train and val loss while the accuracy is just 50% constantly. I think it may the input affect the result.

How can fix code to match the input to three channel?

Answer (score 0):

simply use like 3 channel image - so all channels are same -